# Problema con aplicativo de windows forms a subirlo a Producción

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Agradecería que alguien me dijera a que se debe esto, me han dicho que es por el tema de la configuración regional, que el mensaje que aparece en la primea línea es:

> System.ArgumentException: ORA-1843: not a valid month

Significa que se está enviando una fecha en un formato diferente, lo cual corresponde a un problema de configuración regional.

El funcionamiento del programa no debe depender de la configuración regional del equipo cliente, pues en cada equipo puede ser diferente, que Debo asegurarme de que el programa funcione para cualquier configuración regional.

Siendo este el caso como podría solucionar esto??

Este es el error que me esta saliendo:

> See the end of this message for details on invoking
>
> just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.ArgumentException: ORA-1843: not a valid month
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_Date()
>
> at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection
>   conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize)
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> at chc_deuda.Conectar.EjecutarProcedimiento(String
>   NombreProcedimiento, OracleParameter[] ColeccionParametros)
>
> at chc_deuda.Program.CalcularCuota(DataTable datosCapturados,
>   String CadParametrosAccion, String Envia_Nomina)
>
> at chc_deuda.frmEtapasProceso.button_click(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Acá pongo un ejemplo de un llamado a un procedimiento almacenado:

```
public static void CalcularCuota(DataTable datosCapturados, string CadParametrosAccion, string Envia_Nomina)
        {

            string[] ParametrosAccion = CadParametrosAccion.Split('|');
            int Contador; bool Encontrado; int Posicion;
            string NombreCampoValor;
            DateTime vbleFecha;

            OracleParameter[] ColeccionParametros = new OracleParameter[15];
            ColeccionParametros[0] = new OracleParameter("CODIGO_EMPLEADO", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            ColeccionParametros[1] = new OracleParameter("MONTO", OracleDbType.Double);
            ColeccionParametros[2] = new OracleParameter("PLAZO_MESES", OracleDbType.Int16);
            ColeccionParametros[3] = new OracleParameter("FEC_INI", OracleDbType.Date);
            ColeccionParametros[4] = new OracleParameter("TASA_NA", OracleDbType.Double);
            ColeccionParametros[5] = new OracleParameter("POR_PLJ", OracleDbType.Double);
            ColeccionParametros[6] = new OracleParameter("POR_PLD", OracleDbType.Double);
            ColeccionParametros[7] = new OracleParameter("POR_CES", OracleDbType.Double);
            ColeccionParametros[8] = new OracleParameter("ENVIA_NOMINA", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            ColeccionParametros[9] = new OracleParameter("CODIGO_CONCEPTO", OracleDbType.Int64);
            ColeccionParametros[10] = new OracleParameter("VALOR_CUOTA", OracleDbType.Double, ParameterDirection.Output);
            ColeccionParametros[11] = new OracleParameter("FEC_INI_NUE", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Output);
            ColeccionParametros[12] = new OracleParameter("NUM_PRESTAMO", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output);
            ColeccionParametros[13] = new OracleParameter("MENSAJE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            ColeccionParametros[14] = new OracleParameter("PROYECCION", OracleDbType.Clob, ParameterDirection.Output);

            ColeccionParametros[13].Size = 5000;
            ColeccionParametros[14].Size = 32767;

            foreach (DataRow Registro in datosCapturados.Rows)
            {//Trae todos los valroes de valores de prestamos del registro en el que se encuentra, asi como la etapa del proceso
                ColeccionParametros[0].Value = Registro["COD_EPL"];

                //Valida datos necesarios para calcular cuota
                Registro["OBS_CAL_CUO"] = "";
                if (Registro["PLAZO"].ToString() == "")
                    Registro["OBS_CAL_CUO"] += "Error: Debe indicar el plazo ";
                else
                    ColeccionParametros[2].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Registro["PLAZO"].ToString());
                if (Registro["TASA_NA"].ToString() == "")
                    Registro["OBS_CAL_CUO"] += "Error: Debe indicar tasa ";
                else
                    ColeccionParametros[4].Value = Registro["TASA_NA"];
                if (Registro.Table.Columns.IndexOf("POR_CES") > -1)
                    if (Registro["POR_CES"].ToString() != string.Empty)
                        ColeccionParametros[7].Value = Registro["POR_CES"].ToString();
                    else
                        ColeccionParametros[7].Value = 0;
                else
                    ColeccionParametros[7].Value = 0;
                if (Envia_Nomina == "S")
                {
                    OracleDataReader Capturaconcepto;
                    Capturaconcepto = Program.ConexionBD.CursorDatos("SELECT COD_CON FROM CHC_T_MOD_DEUDA WHERE COD_LIN || COD_MOD = (SELECT COD_LIN || COD_MOD FROM CHC_T_SOL_DEUDA WHERE NUM_SOL = " + Registro["NUM_SOL"] + ")");
                    if (Capturaconcepto.Read())
                        if (Capturaconcepto["COD_CON"].ToString() != "")
                            ColeccionParametros[9].Value = Capturaconcepto["COD_CON"].ToString();
                        else
                            Registro["OBS_CAL_CUO"] += "Error: no está definido el concepto de nómina para la modalidad";
                    else
                        Registro["OBS_CAL_CUO"] += "Error: no está definido el concepto de nómina para la modalidad";
                }

                if (Registro["OBS_CAL_CUO"] == "")
                {
                    ColeccionParametros[8].Value = Envia_Nomina;
                    //Establece si el monto para calcular la cuota lo toma del VLR_SOL o del VLR_APR, dependiendo del parmetro indicado en los parametros de acción de la etapa
                    NombreCampoValor = "VLR_APR";
                    Contador = 0;
                    Encontrado = false;
                    while ((Contador < ParametrosAccion.Length) && (Encontrado == false))
                    {
                        Posicion = ParametrosAccion[Contador].IndexOf("CampoValor");
                        if (Posicion > -1)
                        {
                            NombreCampoValor = ParametrosAccion[Contador].Substring(Posicion + 11).Trim();
                            Encontrado = true;
                        }
                        Contador++;
                    }
                    if (Registro[NombreCampoValor].ToString() != string.Empty)
                        ColeccionParametros[1].Value = Registro[NombreCampoValor].ToString();             //MONTO
                    else
                        ColeccionParametros[1].Value = 0;
                    //Si el usuario indicó fecha de inicio, indica esa fecha para el llamado al procedimiento, sino, toma la fecha actual del sistema
                    if (Registro["FEC_INI"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        vbleFecha = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt16(Registro["FEC_INI"].ToString().Substring(6, 4)), Convert.ToInt16(Registro["FEC_INI"].ToString().Substring(3, 2)), Convert.ToInt16(Registro["FEC_INI"].ToString().Substring(0, 2)));
                        ColeccionParametros[3].Value = vbleFecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    }
                    else
                        ColeccionParametros[3].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    if (Registro["TASA_NA"].ToString() != string.Empty)
                        ColeccionParametros[4].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Registro["TASA_NA"].ToString()); //TASA_NA
                    else
                        ColeccionParametros[4].Value = 0;
                    if (Registro["POR_PLJ"].ToString() != string.Empty)
                        ColeccionParametros[5].Value = Registro["POR_PLJ"].ToString();
                    else
                        ColeccionParametros[5].Value = 0;
                    if (Registro["POR_PLD"].ToString() != string.Empty)
                        ColeccionParametros[6].Value = Registro["POR_PLD"].ToString();
                    else
                        ColeccionParametros[6].Value = 0;
                    //Llama el procedimiento de la base de datos
                    ConexionBD.EjecutarProcedimiento("CHC_PK_DEUDA.CALCULAR_CUOTA", ColeccionParametros);
                    //Si el parámetro MENSAJE (out) no contiene el texto "Error", calculó la cuota
                    if (ColeccionParametros[13].Value.ToString().IndexOf("Error") == -1)      //Si el procedure de la BD no arrojó mensaje de error
                    {
                        Registro["VLR_CUO"] = ColeccionParametros[10].Value.ToString();
                        Registro["FEC_INI"] = ColeccionParametros[11].Value.ToString();
                        //string COD_EPL= Registros["COD_EPL"].;

                        string[] ArrayLineas;
                        String[] Encabezados = new string[9];
                        string[] Linea;
                        string Cadena;
                        Double ValorCuota = Convert.ToDouble(ColeccionParametros[10].Value.ToString()); //Valor cuota
                        Double Valor;

                        //Escribe en el archivo
                        Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleClob TempClob = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleClob)ColeccionParametros[14].Value;
                        Cadena = Convert.ToString(TempClob.Value);
                        ArrayLineas = Cadena.ToString().Split('\n');
                        string Direccion = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\chc_deuda_inf_Proyecciones.html";
                        StreamWriter Archivo = new StreamWriter(Direccion);

                        //Traer Datos informativos de la proyección
                        DataTable InformacionTrabajador = new DataTable();
                        string COD_EPL = (Registro["COD_EPL"].ToString());
                        InformacionTrabajador = Program.ConexionBD.TablaDatos("SELECT APE_EPL, NOM_EPL, CEDULA FROM EMPLEADOS_BASIC WHERE COD_EPL='" + COD_EPL + "'");
                        string Nombre = "";
                        string Apellido = "";
                        string Cedula = "";
                        string NomMod = "";

                        //Se debe obtener la modalidad del prestamo para colocarlo como dato informativo en la proyección
                        DataTable ObtenerModPrestamo = Program.ConexionBD.TablaDatos("SELECT b.NOM_MOD FROM CHC_T_SOL_DEUDA a  INNER JOIN CHC_T_MOD_DEUDA b ON  a.COD_MOD=b.COD_MOD WHERE a.COD_EPL='" + COD_EPL + "' AND a.COD_PRO='" + Program.CodProcesoSel + "' AND a.NUM_SOL=" + Registro["NUM_SOL"].ToString() + "");
                        DataRow datoMod = ObtenerModPrestamo.Rows[0];
                        NomMod = datoMod["NOM_MOD"].ToString();

                        foreach (DataRow valores in InformacionTrabajador.Rows)
                        {
                            Nombre = (valores["NOM_EPL"].ToString());
                            Apellido = (valores["APE_EPL"].ToString());
                            Cedula = (valores["CEDULA"].ToString());

                        }
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<center><h3>Amortización de Endeudamiento </h3></center>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<center><h4>Generado Por : " + Conectar.Usuario.ToString() + "</h4></center>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<center><h4>fecha y hora de Generación : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt") + "</h4></center>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<head> <meta charset=UTF-8><style type = 'text/css'> p.parrafo { font-family:tahoma; font-size:14px;}" +
                                             "table.tablapersonal    { color: black; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(180, 180, 255); border-collapse: collapse; }" +
                                             "table.tablapersonal th { font-family: tahoma; font-size:12px; font-bold:true; border-width: 1px; padding: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(180, 180, 255); }" +
                                             "table.tablapersonal td { font-family: tahoma; font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(180, 180, 255); }" +
                                              "</style></head>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<center><table><tr><td width=350px align=center>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<table class=tablapersonal border=0 >");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Nombre:<td>" +
                            " " + Apellido + " " + Nombre + "</td>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Cédula: <td>" + Cedula + " </td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Modalidad<td>" + NomMod + " </td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Monto: <td>" + Convert.ToDouble(Registro[NombreCampoValor]).ToString("#,##0.00") + "</td>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Valor cuota: <td>" + Convert.ToDouble(Registro["VLR_CUO"]).ToString("#,##0.00") + " </td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Tasa N.A.: <td>" + Registro["TASA_NA"].ToString() + "</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");
                        DateTime Fecha_Inical_Prestamo = Convert.ToDateTime(Registro["FEC_INI"]);
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Fecha inicio: <td>" + Fecha_Inical_Prestamo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " </td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");

                        int Plazo = Convert.ToInt32(Registro["PLAZO"]);
                        DateTime Fecha_Final_Prestamo = Fecha_Inical_Prestamo.AddMonths(Plazo);

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Fecha final: <td>" + Fecha_Final_Prestamo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " </td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Plazo: <td>" + Registro["PLAZO"].ToString() + " meses </td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine(" </table>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td width=350px align=center><table class=tablapersonal border=1>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>%</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Detalle</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Año inicio</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>" + Registro["POR_PLJ"] + " %</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Prima junio</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>" + Fecha_Inical_Prestamo.Year + "</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>" + Registro["POR_PLD"] + " %</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Prima noviembre</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>" + Fecha_Inical_Prestamo.Year + "</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr>");
                        if (Registro.Table.Columns.IndexOf("POR_CES") > -1)
                            Archivo.WriteLine("<td>" + Registro["POR_CES"] + " %</td>");
                        else
                            Archivo.WriteLine("<td>0 %</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>Cesantias</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<td>" + Fecha_Inical_Prestamo.Year + "</td>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("</tr>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine(" </table>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("</table></center>");

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<br><div style='text-align:center'> <table class='tablapersonal'><tr><td>");


                        //Define los encabezados

                        Archivo.WriteLine("<b>Num Item</b>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<th>Tipo Cuota</th>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<th>Fecha</th>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<th>Valor Cuota</th>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<th>Interés</th>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<th>Capital</th>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<th>Abono Extra</th>");
                        Archivo.WriteLine("<th>Nuevo Saldo</th>");


                        Archivo.WriteLine("<tr><td align=center>0<td><td width=90px><td width=90px><td width=90px><td width=90px><td width=90px><td width=100px align=right>" + Convert.ToDouble(Registro[NombreCampoValor]).ToString("#,##0.00"));

                        for (int NumLinea = 1; NumLinea < ArrayLineas.Length; NumLinea++)
                        {
                            Linea = ArrayLineas[NumLinea].Split('|');
                            NumCuo = NumLinea + 1;

                            if (Linea.Length > 1)
                            {

                                Cadena = "<tr><td align=center>" + Linea[0];                                  //Num item

                                Cadena = Cadena + "<td align=center>" + Linea[1];                             //Tipo de cuota
                                Cadena = Cadena + "<td align=center>" + Linea[5];                             //Fecha
                                if (Linea[1] == "O")
                                    Cadena = Cadena + "<td align=right>" + ValorCuota.ToString("#,##0.00");                 //Valor cuota
                                else
                                    Cadena = Cadena + "<td align=right>" + Convert.ToDouble(Linea[8]).ToString("#,##0.00"); //Valor cuota extra

                                if (Linea[6] != "")
                                    Valor = Convert.ToDouble(Linea[6]);
                                else
                                    Valor = 0;
                                Cadena = Cadena + "<td align=right>" + Valor.ToString("#,##0.00");           //Interés
                                if (Linea[7] != "")
                                    Valor = Convert.ToDouble(Linea[7]);
                                else
                                    Valor = 0;
                                Cadena = Cadena + "<td align=right>" + Valor.ToString("#,##0.00");           //Capital
                                if (Linea[8] != "")
                                    Valor = Convert.ToDouble(Linea[8]);
                                else
                                    Valor = 0;
                                Cadena = Cadena + "<td align=right>" + Valor.ToString("#,##0.00");           //Abono Extra
                                if (Linea[9] != "")
                                    Valor = Convert.ToDouble(Linea[9]);
                                else
                                    Valor = 0;
                                Cadena = Cadena + "<td align=right>" + Valor.ToString("#,##0.00");           //Nuevo saldo
                                Archivo.WriteLine(Cadena);
                            }
                        }




                        //Cadena = ColeccionParametros["PROYECCION"].Value.ToString().Replace(";", "<td>");
                        //Cadena = Cadena.Replace("\n", "</tr><tr><td>");
                        //Archivo.WriteLine (Cadena);
                        Archivo.Close();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Registro["VLR_CUO"] = null;
                        Registro["FEC_INI"] = null;
                    }
                    Registro["OBS_CAL_CUO"] = ColeccionParametros[13].Value.ToString().Substring(0, Math.Min(ColeccionParametros[13].Value.ToString().Length, 200));
                    if (Envia_Nomina == "S")
                    {
                        if (!ColeccionParametros[13].Value.ToString().Contains("Error"))
                        {
                            Registro["FEC_ENV_NOM"] = DateTime.Now;
                            Registro["NUM_CUO"] = ColeccionParametros[12].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Registro["VLR_CUO"] = null;
                    Registro["FEC_INI"] = null;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: veo que ejecutas un procedure por medio de `EjecutarProcedimiento()`, ahora bien usas parametros para pasar los valores? podrias poner el codigo de como defines el OracleCommand para asignar los valores que requiere el procedure

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es separar la fecha en año, mes y día, enviarlos separados y una vez recibidos los datos no te dará error y puedes crear la variable de tipo fecha con estos datos.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, si utilizo parámetros para pasar los valores,  de esta manera definí el OracleCommand:  OracleCommand Comando = new OracleCommand(NombreProcedimiento, Conexion); donde la conexión esta definida como:        public static OracleConnection Conexion = new OracleConnection();

Comment: mmm porque defines el OracleConnection public y static, eso no esta bueno, podrias poner el codigo de como defines estos objetos y el Parameters del command

Comment: @LeandroTuttini public void EjecutarProcedimiento(string nombreProcedimiento, OracleParameter[] ColeccionParametros)
{
OracleParameter ParametroNuevo = new OracleParameter();
OracleCommand Comando = new OracleCommand(NombreProcedimiento, Conexion);Comando.Parameters.Clear();
Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
for (i = 0; i < ColeccionParametros.Count(); i++)
{ 
Comando.Parameters.Add(ColeccionParametros[i]);
}
Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
for (i = 0; i < Comando.Parameters.Count; i++)
{
ColeccionParametros[i] = Comando.Parameters[i];
}
Comando.Parameters.Clear();
}

Comment: @LeandroTuttini , todo eso viene de una libreria que se llama using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;, y el método sirve para poder hacer llamados de procedimientos almacenados de oracle

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, acabo de adicionar a la edición de la pregunta un método que hace el llamado al ejecutarProcedimiento, yo creo que el problema es por esos formatos de fecha que utilizo ahí, pero no se como hacer para que eso me quede funcionando en los computadores de los clientes

Comment: Que forma tan rara de agregar los parametros.. si es mucho mas facil hacer OracleParameters.Add() y pasarle el tipo y el valor.. y solita se va a encargar de acomodarlo como corresponda...

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esto a ver si te puede servir: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleGlobalizationClass.htm

Comment: @Pikoh puede ser, pero como hago entonces para aplicarlo en todo mi proyecto???

Comment: Yo nunca lo he usado, no tengo experiencia con oracle. Pero en el enlace tienes un ejemplo de código, y entiendo que una vez lo aplicas, esto se mantiene durante toda la aplicación.

Comment: @JuanMartínTabordaGarcía eso que colocaste de solucionado no es válido, en su lugar usa la zona de respuestas para colocar y explicar como lo solucionaste

Answer (score 1):

la solución fue muy sencilla, solo fue implementar y utilizar `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` en todos los formatos de fecha y números decimales. Muchas gracias por sus valiosos aportes.

Answer (score 0):

Debes pasarle la fecha como tipo DateTime al parametro.